# Require route value in Razor Pages for folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

In ASP.NET Core Razor Pages, how do I set up routing for a folder to require a particular route id to be present? Here is my folder structure:

```
[Pages]
 - Index.cshtml
 - GeneralPage.cshtml
 - [Company]
    - Billing.cshtml
    - Manage.cshtml
    - Users.cshtml
```

Any page within the "Company" folder should have a route parameter (`integer {companyId}`) before the page name. The following should all be valid requests:

- /Index
- /GeneralPage
- /Company/1234/Billing
- /Company/1234/Manage
- /Company/1234/Users

The following should fail:

- /Company/Billing
- /Company/Manage
- /Company/Users

[AddFolderRouteModelConvention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.pageconventioncollection.addfolderroutemodelconvention?view=aspnetcore-2.2) sounds  promising, but its use is not obvious to me.

**Any suggestions on the most straightforward way to achieve the routing above?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a general solution, but works for the simple layout above:

```
options.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention("/Company", model =>
{
    Regex templatePattern = new Regex("^Company/");
    foreach (var selector in model.Selectors)
    {
        selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template =
            templatePattern.Replace(selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template, "Company/{companyId}/");
    }
});
```